# How to Move UIRefreshControl to Top of the reversed TableView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am using reverse order tableview by using `UIView().transform` property. Everything works perfect but the only one problem is `UIRefreshControl` is not gone up to top. Also the pull to refresh works at bottom level instead of **top.**

**Code:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var countries = ["1","2"]
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      
        let control = UIRefreshControl()
        control.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Refreshing")
        self.tableView.refreshControl = control
        
        control.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
        self.tableView.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        
        self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
    }
    
    
    @objc private func refresh(){
           
 
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
    
//             self.tableView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
           }
       }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return self.countries.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        
        let label  = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        
        label.text = self.countries[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)
        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func insertCell(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
        self.countries = ["New Country \(self.countries.count)"] + self.countries
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .bottom)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
    }
    
}
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

How to move the pull to refresh functionality to top? Any other solution for this? Thanks in advance....

Comment: Why do you want to reverse tableview in first place?

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger For Message View controller (Chat between two users)